# Inconsistent Booting and Slow Performance

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive

**Symptoms**

Windows 10 (ver 10.0.18363 Build 18363) PC will only boot successfully after multiple attempts. When it does NOT succeed, one of the following happens:

1. Blue screen that says "Your PC/Device needs to be repaired. The application or operating system couldn't be loaded because a required file is missing or contains errors. Error code: 0x0000185." The file cited as missing varies. I've seen 
   \Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe, \system32\config\system, and \system32\winload.efi
2. Goes to BIOS page

When it does succeed, there are still problems about half of the time. Applications will load way slower than usual (i.e. games will become unplayable), load times for Windows functions will be exaggerated, etc. Gets fixed by restarting until it works again.

**Background**

I installed Windows 10 on my PC using an USB drive. It is custom built. The first hard drive I had on this PC was defective (leading to some similar issues + a disk-not-found error), so I replaced it and reinstalled Windows clean. Since then, symptoms have improved and the disk-not-found error has disappeared, but the PC is still difficult to use. I have tried using chkdsk.exe, mdsched.exe and sfc.exe to no avail. If I recall correctly, chksdk actually found/fixed errors without solving these problems altogether.

**Parts**

Samsung SSD 860 EVO 500GB

NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060

AMD Ryzen 5 2600

2x Corsair 8 GB RAM

B450 Tomahawk Motherboard

I greatly appreciate any tips/help!

Answer (score 0):

Please include the version of Windows 10 (type winver in the search box and press enter).  Quote the OS Built part xxxxx.xxx e.g 18363.815.  FYI: since Windows 10 was first put out MS has said that this will be the last named version of Windows ever - all future versions will be just numbers (the ones called OS Build).  Saying one has windows 10 installed will be (already is?) like saying one has Linux installed - not informative enough to troubleshoot problems that are likely to be software problems.
Otherwise the standard BSOD potential solutions for intermittent problems apply:  update bios: update windows; run sfc /scannow from the command prompt (type cmd in search box and press enter, highlight and right-click "run as administrator').  If the standard solutions do not work then report this in your question.

Comment: I have now added the Win10 version in my post and will update the BIOS.

Comment: It's working sooo much better now. I updated my BIOS and AMD driver. After multiple restarts/on-off cycles, no errors. This was unthinkable before.

Comment: Despite improvements, I still get some of these boot errors (missing file blue screen). Please let me know if you have more general tips for this